# NullPointer Exception while getting Reference in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch data from my Firebase Database. I've initialized a variable called as `tData`, which has some inputs from my Activity. In which I'm going to fetch data, `tData` has been publically defined.

```
 tData[10] =getArguments().getString("sLst");
```

I used a `toast` to check if the contents are empty or not, and they aren't, `tData[10]` has data, but still during the below operation

```
 DatabaseReference databaseReference4 = firebaseDatabase.getReference("USERS/"+tData[10]+"/sList"); **
    databaseReference4.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            tData[6]=dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I get an error saying

```
NullPointerException,com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(java.lang.String) on a null object reference at **
```

any inputs would be helpful

Comment: Did you call FirebaseApp.initializeApp()?

Answer (score 1):

Did you initialize firebaseDatabase object?

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

Make sure you add this.